# Styling polygon dash-dot borders in GeoServer using SLD

Tags: border, polygon, geoserver, sld

I want to draw polygon borders using a pattern of dashes and other symbols like triangles or circles but most polygons share borders so I get an undesired result.

Using this SLD code:

```
  <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
    <se:Fill>
      <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#cf72be</se:SvgParameter>
    </se:Fill>
  </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
  <se:LineSymbolizer>
    <se:Stroke>
      <se:GraphicStroke>
        <se:Graphic>
          <se:Mark>
            <se:WellKnownName>circle</se:WellKnownName>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#333333</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
          </se:Mark>
          <se:Size>6</se:Size>
        </se:Graphic>
      </se:GraphicStroke>
      <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-dasharray">6 18</se:SvgParameter>
    </se:Stroke>
  </se:LineSymbolizer>
  <se:LineSymbolizer>
    <se:Stroke>
      <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#AA0000</se:SvgParameter>
      <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-dasharray">10 14</se:SvgParameter>
      <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-dashoffset">14</se:SvgParameter>
    </se:Stroke>
  </se:LineSymbolizer>
```

I get this result in GeoServer:

[image: GeoServer layer Preview]

Is there any way to avoid having two overlapping border lines or to make symbols perfectly overlap?

Comment: this would be better asked on https://gis.stackexchange.com